# Rake task not sending mail rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rake, rake-task

I've written my first rake task in rails, I've set it up with the Heroku scheduler and it is getting run, however the mail isn't getting sent. My mail settings are fine as I'm using it for various other things, I would imagine it's a problem with my code in the rake task. Any help would be much appreciated.

## lib/tasks/uncomplete_form.rake

```
desc "Remind users if they haven't completed quote form"
task uncomplete_form: :environment do
    puts 'Reminding users of uncomplete quote form'
    date = Date.parse('december 18 2016')
    quickcontacts = Quickcontact.where(created_at: date.midnight..Time.now)
        quickcontacts.each do |quickcontact|
            next unless quickcontact.created_at > 1.hour.ago
                 if quickcontact.p_p = nil
                     QuickcontactMailer.uncomplete_form(@quickcontact).deliver
                 end
            end
    puts 'done.'
end
```

By running rake uncomplete_form I get

Reminding users of uncomplete quote form

done.

And running 
    heroku run rake uncomplete_form
I get

```
Reminding users of uncomplete quote form
 Quickcontact Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "quickcontacts".* FROM "quickcontacts" WHERE ("quickcontacts"."created_at" BETWEEN '2016-12-18 00:00:00.000000' AND '2016-12-20 12:09:23.683977')
done.
```

It doesn't seem to be picking up any quickcontacts - however if in the console I run:

```
date = Date.parse('december 18 2016')
```

followed by

```
quickcontacts = Quickcontact.where(created_at: date.midnight..Time.now)
```

It does find the expected contacts

Comment: Might be a timezone issue. Heroku schedular will work on UTC. Try to debug on that way.

Comment: I thought about that, but UTC time is 2 hours in front of mine and some of the quickcontacts were created yesterday (december 19th) so it shouldn't make a difference I don't think.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried

```
QuickcontactMailer.uncomplete_form(@quickcontact).deliver_now
```

?

Edit: What's .p_p supposed to be? You're doing assignment in that if clause instead of what I presume should have been comparison (?)

```
if quickcontact.p_p = nil
```

Comment: Ah how stupid of me... it's supposed to be checking that p_p is nil - not assigning a value. (p_p is the last part of the quote form, so if that's not complete - the form is uncomplete - firing the uncomplete form mail)
So I should use something like 'if quickcontact.p_p == nil', or better yet 'if quickcontact.p_p.nil?'      I imagine that should do it. Thanks, I will let you know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Solved: Two bad errors on my part. Thanks for the help with the first @matija. The problem was with my rake task code. The first error was where I had 'if quickcontact.p_p = nil' needed to be changed to 'if quickcontact.p_p.nil?' - I was accidentally assigning nil value, rather than checking it. 
The second error was that in the next line down, quickcontact should not have been an instance variable. This is the updated, functioning code:

```
desc "Remind users if they haven't completed quote form"
task uncomplete_form: :environment do
    puts 'Reminding users of uncomplete quote form'
    date = Date.parse('december 18 2016')
    quickcontacts = Quickcontact.where(created_at: date.midnight..Time.now)
        quickcontacts.each do |quickcontact|
            next unless quickcontact.created_at > 1.hour.ago
                if quickcontact.p_p.nil?
                    QuickcontactMailer.uncomplete_form(quickcontact).deliver
            end
        end
puts 'done.'
end
```